# "detail : Invalid signature ." in JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have created login/register API using DRF and JWT token. The api works fine, it generates the token. Now I have another app that provides a capability to add notices to authenticated users only.
When I try to test, I supply the header as `Authorization JWT <token>` in postman, but I get the following as the error:

```
"detail : Invalid signature ."
```

I even checked the `token` here https://jwt.io/, it shows `signature verified`.

Now I am unable to detect the problem. I surfed all through the internet but no luck. Please anyone can help me out with this.

For full api you can see it in github [here](https://github.com/Yathartha22/notices-api), and suggest me if I am wrong anywhere.

**views.py**

```
class AddNotice(APIView):

    permission_class = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = AddNoticeSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        serializer = AddNoticeSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AddNoticeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Api
        fields = ('id', 'notice_name', 'notice_desc', 'notice_author', 'notice_valid_till', 'notice_publish_date')

    def create(self, validated_data):
            return Api.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.notice_name =  validated_data.get('name', instance.notice_name)
        instance.notice_desc = validated_data.get('category', instance.notice_desc)
        instance.notice_author = validated_data.get('subcategory', instance.notice_author)
        instance.notice_valid_till = validated_data.get('subcategory', instance.notice_valid_till)
        instance.notice_publish_date = validated_data.get('subcategory', instance.notice_publish_date)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**Update:**

I tried in postman. something like this

[image]

Comment: Please supply the exact request that you made and what headers, you can use `curl` format

Comment: I use postman, hope it would be all right. I have added an image to the question. Have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have `get_by_natural_key` method defined in you manager.

This is the method that the library uses to retrieve user object:
https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/0a0bd402ec21fd6b9a5f715d114411836fbb2923/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L59

To resolve it, simply add this method to your `AccountManager`:

```
def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
    return self.get(username=username)
```

Not sure why this isn't documented in more detail in `django-rest-framework-jwt` docs..

Comment: One thing is that after adding the above I can login only by username if I want to add another means of login what should I do?

Comment: You would need to change logic accordingly. 1. Define `JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER` which by default takes username field; 2. change `get_by_natural_key` to get object by the field you want instead of username (the value passed is returned by `JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER` handler. The `username` variable is kinda misleading imo, they should change it to smth more general..

Answer (score 0):

found that the 'Invalid Signature' error comes up when I create a custom User model. I resolved this by:

Instantiating a model based on Django's User model:

``

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
.....
```

``

In settings.py, use AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to the custom user model.

``

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

``

where 'user.User' points to User model in user app.

Proceed with token generation. The token will validate now.